# why is Python looking for dev_appserver.py in the google_appengine folder

Tags: python-2.7, google-cloud-platform

When going trough this tutorial [Build an Android App Using Firebase and the App Engine Flexible Environment](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/mobile-firebase-app-engine-flexible) I get an Python error.

why is Python looking for **dev_appserver.py** in the **google_appengine** folder?

The **dev_appserver.py** exist in the **google-cloud-sdk\bin** folder

How can i resolve this?

Here is the Exception:

```
[INFO] python.exe: can't open file 'C:\GoogleCloudSDK\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
Exception in thread "standard-out-redirection-devappserver" java.lang.RuntimeException: The Java Dev Server has stopped.
        at com.google.appengine.gcloudapp.AbstractGcloudMojo$1.run(AbstractGcloudMojo.java:346)
[ERROR] Error: gcloud app command with exit code : 2
[ERROR]
org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error: gcloud app command exit code is: 2
        at com.google.appengine.gcloudapp.AbstractGcloudMojo.startCommand(AbstractGcloudMojo.java:380)
        at com.google.appengine.gcloudapp.GCloudAppRun.execute(GCloudAppRun.java:302)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
```

Comment: Try googling `dev_appserver.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`. You might find some results that help you.